# How can I redirect all requests that points to an actual file or directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, apache2

I am trying to redirect all requests that points to an actual file or directory in the root of my application to a specific php file, using the .htaccess file in the root directory. I want to be able to prevent people from snooping into my application's files and folders, while still controlling what happens to such requests: whether to throw a custome 404 error or not. But I don't know how I can achieve that, (if at all it is possible). I have searched through the StackOverflow and Google too, but found nothing helpful enough. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: What rules have you tried?

Comment: You could take a look at the .htaccess files used by Symfony, they basically are doing what you want, redirecting many requests to either app.php or app_dev.php (https://github.com/symfony/symfony-demo/blob/master/web/.htaccess)

Comment: I have tried these rules:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(public|\.webroot|framework)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1&params=$2 [QSA,L]